# Bootstrap in rails app works only with .scss

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-4

I am currently learning Rails and working on a simple SocialMedia/Blog app.
I am at a point where I have a basic view set up and am attempting to apply BootStrap CSS to it.

I followed the following steps in attempting to apply BootStrap to my application:

1.) added gem 'bootstrap-sass' into gemfile and ran 'bundle install'

2.) added '*=require bootstrap' to application.css

3.) added '//= require bootstrap' to application.js

4.) 
added:

```
<div class="container">
   <%= yield %>
 </div>
```

However when I would open the app, I got an error stating

```
couldn't find file 'bootstrap' with type 'text/css'
```

It would highlight the line "*=require bootstrap"

However, when I changed the extension to application.css.scss and added an @import statement as below, it worked with BootStrap applied

application.css.scss:

```
* This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, 
which will include all the files
* listed below.
*
* Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, 
lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
* vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a 
relative path.
*
* You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll 
appear at the bottom of the
* compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over 
styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
* files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after 
the last require_* statement.
* It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
*
*= require_tree .
*= require bootstrap
*= require_self
*/
@import "bootstrap";
```

So 2 questions...
1.) Why does my app require .scss and @import in order for BootStrap to work  ?

2.) why does my "*=require bootstrap" need to be "*=require_bootstrap"?

THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-sass is a Sass implementation of the bootstrap CSS which is originally written in Less.

If you want *just* the Less css you can get it from getbootstrap.com

If you wish to keep using `bootstrap-sass`:

- You'll need to rename your `application.css` to `application.scss`.
- Remove `*= require bootstrap`.
- Add lines as I indicated below
  starting with `@import`.
- Also you'll want to include the `bootstrap-sprockets`.

This is how my working bootstraped applications's `application.scss` file looks:

```
...
 *
 *= require_self
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
...
```

My `applicaiton.js`

```
...
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//    
...
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
...
```

Checkout this reference https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1/ at the sectioned titled Integrating Bootstrap with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

application.css.scss:

```
*= require bootstrap  #remove it
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
*/
```

application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery
```

And most important is open a new scss file and add :

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: open a new .scss named what? I'm confused why this is needed. I already @import "bootstrap" inside application.cscc.scss

Comment: Don't add `@import "bootstrap"` inside application.css.scss, and the new scss file you can named what ever you want